How to read Liquibase Parameter from Spring Boot Java Class
I have customTaskChange under my liquibase script from which I am invoking spring boot class.. The reason I don't want to pass parameters from liquibase is, these properties are dynamic and whenever it will change it will throw an error for inavlid checksum.
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog
                  http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.6.xsd">

    <changeSet id="update" author="abc" runAlways="true">
        <customChange class="com.med.yc.facility.util.MainConfigurationUpdate"/>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>

And have two custom properties in application.properties
spring.liquibase.parameters.a=dynamic_abc
spring.liquibase.parameters.d=dynamic_def

Now when I am trying to access these properties in java class, it is coming as null
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(LiquibaseProperties.class)
public class MainConfigurationUpdate implements CustomTaskChange {

    private ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor;

    @Value("${a}")
    private String a;
    @Value("${d}")
    private String d;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void execute(Database database) throws CustomChangeException {
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(d);
    }

    @Override
    public String getConfirmationMessage() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws SetupException {
        //do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void setFileOpener(ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor) {
        this.resourceAccessor = resourceAccessor;
    }

    @Override
    public ValidationErrors validate(Database database) {
        return null;
    }
}



Perhaps it's null because the property is not, a or d, it's spring.liquibase.parameters.a or spring.liquibase.parameters.d.  Change your @Value to read, @Value("${spring.liquibase.parameters.a}"). Also, you do not need EnableConfigurationProperties for this, it's not doing anything.

NO, this is not working, there are other properties also like service.name and server.port.... if I try to access them using @Value("${service.name}") then also I am getting null

The main thing here is this class has been invoked from liquibase script so probably it doesn't have application context

So you're trying to use Spring's property injection without using Sping?

Yes, liquibase chagesets get executed at the startup of service only, so there will be no application context
